# OS X Finder-like unarchiving in Windows

Tags: windows-explorer, finder, archiving

I've gotten quite used to the OS X way of unarchiving, i.e. double-clicking on an archive file unzips it in the current directory. If everything in the archive is contained within a single directory, it extracts straight-away, if not, it creates a directory (same name as the file) and all your stuff ends up there.

Most of the time, that's exactly what I need, I don't really need a pop-up of winrar or 7-zip, showing me the package contents. Is there a simple enough way to do the same with Windows? I'd be fine with some registry editing or scripting, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

7-Zip does offer that functionality from the context menu (right-click) - see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: First of all, I'd need that as a default action, not in a context menu. And most Windows archiving applications I've seen offer exactly those two features: Extract it *right here*, or extract it to a directory named <filename>. I need the latter, but only if it isn't already all in one directory. Or else, I just end up with "dir_name/dir_name/*.*". Only create a directory to prevent clobbering the current one.